# Sharepoint Online spfx web part to display Saved Document Library View

Tags: sharepoint-online, spfx, spfx-webparts

I've created a custom web part that displays documents from a relative URL.

```
const queryUrlGetAllItems: string = this._webAbsoluteUrl + `/_api/web/GetFolderByServerRelativeUrl('${libraryRelativeUrl}')/Files?$expand=ListItemAllFields`;
```

My client has many custom document library views that have many filters and sorting options.

Is there a way to use the API (or some other way) to retrieve all documents from a direct document library view?

ex. https://contoso.sharepoint.com/sites/CommSite/MyDocumentsFolder/Forms/AllItems.aspx?viewid=e3025c96%2D13a9%2D4854%2Da3cf%2Da1797d31e2c7

Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use code like the one found in [this sample](https://github.com/SharePoint/sp-dev-fx-webparts/blob/master/samples/react-adaptivecards/src/webparts/adaptiveCardHost/AdaptiveCardHostWebPart.ts) in the `_loadDataFromList`.

It uses PnPJs, but you can:

```
    const list = await sp.web.lists.getById("yourlistid"); // or get by title

    // Get the view definition
      const view = await list.getView("your view id")();
      const viewSchema = view.HtmlSchemaXml;

    // Get the data as returned by the view
    const { Row: data } = await list.renderListDataAsStream({
      ViewXml: viewSchema
    });
```

I hope it helps?

Comment: This looks like it should lead me in the right direction. Thank you!

Comment: Hi @Hugo do you have any insight on what's happening with updating web parts? https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/279559/updating-client-side-web-app-in-sharepoint-online-app-library-not-updating