# Updating Client Side Web App in Sharepoint Online App Library - Not Updating

Tags: sharepoint-online, spfx, spfx-webparts

I have an app deployed on Sharepoint with 3 Client Side Web Parts.
When i first add it, it's version is = 1.0.0.0.

When I make changes to the solution:
Change version to 2.0.0.0
`gulp bundle --ship`
`gulp package-solution --ship`

Then upload the .sppk file to the "Apps for Sharepoint" screen. I overwrite the old file. It's enabled, deployed, with no errors.

- I check in the changes (I've tried not checking in too)

But, then I go into the Site contents and the app is still showing v1.0.0.0.

The only way to get this to update is to:

1. Go into the "Classic Experience"
2. Remove App
3. Delete from Recycling Bin
4. Add app again in "Add an app" page.
5. Sometimes I have to do this a couple times for it to work.

Am I doing something incorrectly? Is the app being cached by sharepoint or something?

In any downtime before the updated app is successfully added, all pages where those web parts exist display nothing.

Any help would be appreciated. Thank you!!

Comment: Now I'm unable to Updated my Web parts with this approach either. After updating to 4.0.0.0 I can only see the 3.0.0.0 web parts :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to determine that the "Modern" view of the "Apps For Sharepoint" page may be the culprit.

After switching that back to "Classic" i was able use the above approach. It still isn't great, but it works for now.

__ Edit __
It looks like classic mode allows to overwrite packages as expected. Disregard, community.

__ UPDATE __
When running into a similar updating issue i found this page by going into "Classic" mode on the "Site Contents" page. Then clicking the "About" button. If there is an update you can click "Get It" here.
[image]